# Android switchpreference how can i set the switch preference default value?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a switch preference and want it to be defaulted "ON"...
in the xml,

```
<SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="PromoNotificationOnOff"
        android:title="@string/Snotification_enable" />
```

and in class,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);


}
```

why isn't it working? What is missing? Thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `MainActivity onCreate` method add this line

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);
```

You can read about it at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues(android.content.Context, int, boolean)

Comment: The XML "android:defaultValue" tag is absolutely correct. Updating the value (overriding it) in the code is a redundant, and could cause confusion later if both are left in place.

However, when debugging this code, the "defaults" for preference items often don't take until the Application Data is cleared in the Android Settings.

Comment: @gtcompscientist before you comment and down vote you should read the reference link. If that is too much trouble then you should at least read the doc on setDefaultValues() to know what the parameters stand for. Where in the solution I provided that updates the value set in the xml? The solution I provided is absolutely correct and clear if one know what the method setDefaultValues() is.

Comment: That gtcompscientist 's comment is upvoted multiple times might be misleading for anyone reading it now. As Hoan Nguyen pointed out, the `setDefaultValues()` method uses the default values from the preferences xml. It will not override already set preferences, even with the readAgain parameter set "true" (possibly better if you have only few entries). That still holds for the new androidx preferences library. The answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct just use switchPreferenceCompact instead of SwitchPreference

```
     <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="promoNofitficationOnOff"
        app:summaryOff="@string/notification_summary_off"
        app:summaryOn="@string/notification_summary_on"
        app:defaultValue="true"
        app:title="@string/promo_notification_title" />
```